# Specifying exact space between two words for fully justified text

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, justification

Is there a way of specifying the *exact space*, in some given unit, between two words when the text is fully justified? I normally use \hspace{x cm} when I want to increase/decrease the space *relative* to the original spacing post-justification by x cm. But how can I specify an exact space such that the spacing between the words does not change, regardless of what justification does to the *base* spacing?

Comment: Did you try to put the words into an hbox? Connect them with your hspace command without spaces. Just an idea - no latex available at the moment...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\hbox` or `\mbox` solution is good. Another possibility is to eliminate existing space

```
\newcommand\sep[1]{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\unskip 
  \nobreak % optional
  \hspace{#1}\ignorespaces
}

specifying the exact \sep{4mm} space, in some given unit
```

This eliminates white space from `\hspace` commands or space characters before the measured gap, but ignores only space characters (or line-ends) afterwards. The `\nobreak` is on the assumption that you don't want a line break there. The `\leavevmode` makes sure you aren't berween paragraphs, preventing the `\unskip` commands from eliminating `\vspace` glue. Two `\unskip`s allow for `\hspace` plus a space character preceding the gap.

Comment: Nice to see a compliment like "The solution is good"... thx ;-)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like

```
I love \mbox{big\hspace{2em}green} apples more than the small red ones.
```

Note: Usually it is not a good idea to fiddle with interword spacing... :-(

Comment: @egreg answer updated - you're right... :-)

Comment: Yes, I'd upvote it again if I could.